# Bounding $\int_{B(0,r)}uDu\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}dx$ by $\int_{B(0,r)}|Du|^2dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u \in C^\infty(B(0,r))$. In a textbook I am reading, $\int_{B(0,r)}uDu\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}dx$ is bounded by $C \int_{B(0,r)}|Du|^2dx$ for some constant (independent of $u$). Why is this true?

Comment: Are you sure that these are the only hypothesis? I can't even see why the first integral is not $\infty$. Is $B(0,r)$ the open ball, or the closed ball?

Comment: if $u\in C(\overline{B(0,r)})\cap C^1(B(0,r))$, with $u=0$ in the boundary and $u,\nabla u\in L^2(B(0,r))$, then this is true by Holder inequality and Poincare inequalite.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomás  notes, something else must be assumed about $u$. Indeed, if $\int_{B(0,r)}Du\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}dx$ is not zero, then adding a constant to $u$ we can make $\int_{B(0,r)}uDu\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}dx$ arbitrarily large, without changing $  \int_{B(0,r)}|Du|^2dx$.

If $u$ vanishes on the boundary, or has mean zero, then the Poincaré inequality applies:
$$\int_{B(0,r)} u^2 \le C \int_{B(0,r)} |Du|^2  $$
and the claim follows from Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\left(\int_{B(0,r)}uDu\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}dx\right)^2 \le \int_{B(0,r)} u^2 \cdot \int_{B(0,r)} |Du|^2
$$